# Omit page reference if target is on the same or the facing page

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals, calculations, double-sided, ifthenelse

I'm working on a two-side `scrbook` in which references are made to other sections, figures, etc. If the target is on the very same page, I want to omit a page reference in the text (i.e., if we're on page 30, there souldn't be a text that says "c.f. p. 30"). For a label #1, this achieved with the following command:

```
\newcounter{samepage}
\newcommand{\IfRefOnSamePage}[3]{%
    \stepcounter{samepage}%
    \label{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getpagerefnumber{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}}}%
    {#2}%
    {#3}%
}
```

It outputs #2 if the target is on the same page, otherwise #3.

Now since the book is two-sided, I am counting on the readers to also not need a reference if the target is on the facing page. I thought it should be a simple task to extend the condition to catch these cases, using the `xifthen` package and `Ifthispageeven`/-`odd`:

```
\ifthenelse{%
    \equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getpagerefnumber{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}}%
    \OR
    \Ifthispageodd{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}-1}}{false}%
    \OR
    \Ifthispageeven{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}+1}}{false}%
}%
{#2}%
{#3}%
```

This attempt yields numerous errors "Undefined control sequence", "Missing number", "Argument has an extra }", and so on. I triple-checked, but is there something wrong with my `\ifthenelse` syntax? Or with the way I'm trying to do the +/- 1 calculations?

---

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{samepage}
\newcommand{\IfRefOnSamePage}[3]{%
    \stepcounter{samepage}%
    \label{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getpagerefnumber{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}}}%
    {#2}%
    {#3}%
}

\newcommand{\IfRefOnDoublePage}[3]{%
    \stepcounter{samepage}%
    \label{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}%
    \ifthenelse{%
        \equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getpagerefnumber{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}}%
        \OR
        \Ifthispageodd{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}-1}}{false}%
        \OR
        \Ifthispageeven{\equal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{cmd:samepage-\thesamepage}+1}}{false}%
    }%
    {#2}%
    {#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{First page}
Text.
\newpage

\section{Second page}
% This works:
Read more about this\IfRefOnSamePage{target}{ on this page}{ on page \pageref{target}}.
% This throws errors, but also works:
Read more about this\IfRefOnDoublePage{target}{ here}{ on page \pageref{target}}.

\subsection{I am the reference target}
\label{target}
Text.
\newpage

\section{Third page}
% This works as expected, but it yields a reference I actually don't want:
Read more about this\IfRefOnSamePage{target}{ on this page}{ on page \pageref{target}}.
% This doesn't:
Read more about this\IfRefOnDoublePage{target}{ here}{ on page \pageref{target}}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you also post the three pages of text so that we have a MWE to start from?

Comment: see the `varioref` package

Comment: I added the MWE, thanks.
@David, thanks for the tip, however from the first glance I'd say I need something else since my references are not printed in the text but should be placed in the margin. So instead of the `\pageref` as in the MWE, I'd use some customised `\marginpar` in which the actual reference is printed.

Comment: you can use varioref (or copy its code) to set up the required test. What you then print is just details.